# Spark 2.2 toPandas() is returning Py4JError

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Currently refactoring some PySpark code and this specific snippet is causing me issues whereas it has ran fine before:

```
zip_table=spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat").schema(schemas.zip_schema).load(path_to_file,header=True)
zip_pandas = zip_table.toPandas()
```

running into:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o167.get.
: java.util.NoSuchElementException: spark.sql.execution.pandas.respectSessionTimeZone
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$$anonfun$getConfString$2.apply(SQLConf.scala:1175)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$$anonfun$getConfString$2.apply(SQLConf.scala:1175)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf.getConfString(SQLConf.scala:1175)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.RuntimeConfig.get(RuntimeConfig.scala:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Other Spark Dataframes are successfully able to call toPandas() while others such as this return the same error.

The file in question is not particularly big and should be able to fit in the driver no problem. Also, I know it may be better to just load it into Pandas directly and not convert from Spark, but there is further logic in the code that requires both Spark/Pandas dataframes (and a later re-architecture of this work will address this issue).